# Open a port for bittorrent transmission

Tags: ubuntu, port-forwarding, bittorrent

I am using deluge as my bittorrent client in Ubuntu 14.04. I want to open a port for speeding up the downloading.

I did the following things:

1. disabled firewall by `sudo ufw disable`
2. changed settings in deluge as follows
   [image]
3. created a custom service for port forwarding as follows
   [image]

***(UPnP is off in my router)

but still testing for active port gives a negative result.

What is the correct way of port forwarding???